Тестирование на переполнение и знак. DEBUG директивы
Существуют ли какие-то директивы компилятора, позволяющие при выполнении арифметики и присвоений целочисленных значений включать проверки на переполнение и присвоение беззнаковому числу отрицательного значения? По типу директив _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL, CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL (Visual Studio), _GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS (Qt) для включения проверок на валидность и диапазон в контейнерах и их итераторах. Предполагаю так же, что проверку "отрицательное в беззнаковое" можно интерпретировать, как переполнение, но не знаю, может быть есть уже какое-то устоявшееся мнение по этому поводу.
По сути, я тоже пишу свой контейнер (многомерный массив, в образовательных целях), но кроме указанных проверок хотелось бы еще добавить дэбаги на проверку, что мне не подсовывают отрицательный размер одной из размерностей в конструкторе, но тащить эти проверки в релиз не хочется. И плодить свои директивы не очень красиво, если что-то подобное уже есть в компиляторах.
Всё, что сам нашел на эту тему, это примеры реализации проверок в рантайм. Да, и они мне нужны. Но вопрос не в них. Я хочу, чтобы они (эти проверки) были по умолчанию отключены, но для тестирования можно было бы включить.
Добавлено:
Совсем забыл упомянуть про assert. assert можно было бы, но у него слишком широкий диапазон. Один NDEBUG на всё про всё. Просто, если тут ему место, то почему тогда ему не место в стандартных контейнерах? Не знаю... Но если это действительно место для assert по канону, то пусть будет assert. Но я действительно пока не знаю.

@AlexF да, прошу прощения, забыл упомянуть про assert.
assert можно было бы. Но у него слишком широкий диапазон. Один NDEBUG на всё про всё. Просто если тут ему место, то почему тогда ему не место в стандартных контейнерах?

Пожалуй добавлю упоминание assert в вопрос

Используйте для размеров size_t (он беззнаковый) и оставьте все проверки на совести вызывающего. Да, это противоречит тому, чему учат всех студентов, но на практике дает лучшие результаты (в конце-концов просто отсеивает непригодных к программированию) / Что касается проверки переполений, то их надо выполнять перед операцией

@avp если честно, то на своей небольшой практике, когда пишу разные программулинки чисто для себя (только я это на Delphi делал), я так и делаю. Но сейчас то мне как раз и надо разобраться как оно работает на самом деле в новом для меня языке. Пощупать все эти assert, SFINAE, cast... Как минимум здесь буду мучать себя ибо на платные курсы денях у меня нету (жаба съела).

assert это просто макрос, в котрый вы подсовываете собственное выражение и если его результат это false, то печатается сообщение и вызывается abort (емнип). cast -- ну там все довольно очевидно, для целых разных размеров правая часть меняет свой размер до размера левой с учетом знака (если она была длиннее, то просто режется) и биты пересылаются в левую часть (в общем, просто как палка и веревка ... (если понимаешь, как это сделано на уровне машиных инструкций))

@avp И да, конечно, для массива размерности (внутреннее поле моего TMatrix) я использую беззаковый тип и просто делаю cast при инициализации/изменении размеров. Эти проверки чисто для дэбага.

Так и сделайте конструктор тоже только с типом size_t для передачи размеров

@avp не в этом дело. Даже если конструктор будет только на size_t он скушает и int. По фен-шую в таких случаях (умные дядьки говорят) нужно оставить возможность для включения проверок. В стандартной библиотеке, по крайней мере, сделано так.

imho единственная проверка, имеющая какой-то смысл, это проверить, что конечный размер всех структур не выходит за разумные границы (скажем, 40 бит виртуальной адресации (на самом деле и это безумно много))

Проверки на переполнение входят в -fsanitize=undefined (GCC, Clang; в MSVC вроде нет эквивалента). (Я бы еще добавил -fsanitize=address, который отлавливает неправильную работу с памятью - вот его MSVC умеет.)
По умолчанию там только знаковое (потому что беззнаковое легально), но если покопаться в настройках, возможно его тоже можно отлавливать.

Но, именно для этой цели - проверить, что аргумент неотрицательный - assert() мне нравится больше.

у него слишком широкий диапазон. Один NDEBUG на всё про всё.

Ну тогда сделайте свой макрос в духе assert(), но который можно включать/выключать отдельно.


_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS (Qt)

Он не из Qt, он из libstdc++ - стандартной библиотеки С++ компилятора GCC.
Есть еще _GLIBCXX_DEBUG, который включает больше проверок.

Огромное спасибо. Очень убедительно и информативно.
Я пока попридержу галочку "принято" не на долго.

Видимо Вы правы на счёт собственных макросов проверок. Я же типа библиотеку пишу по сути, даром, что учебную. Так что добавлю собственные defin'ы типа SIB_MATRIX_DEBUG_ЧЕГОТОТАМ. Не знаю, может их стоит завязать на разные defin'ы разных компиляторов, но это пока точно выше моих сил.

@HalturinEvgeniy Мне кажется ваш дефайн должен быть отдельно от дефайнов компилятора, а то для юзеров будет неожиданность.

Я имею в виду, например, если типа включен debug на проверку диапазонов для контейнеров, то мой контейнер тоже типа должен реагировать соответственно. Но да, это я уже не буду реализовывать. Слишком сложно для меня. Лучше это просто задокументирую.

Прокомментирую некоторые пункты:

присвоение беззнаковому числу отрицательного значения

Clang/GCC - компилируйте с флагом -Wsign-conversion:
unsigned foo(int a){ return a; }
// Без -Wsign-conversion: OK
// C   -Wsign-conversion: conversion to 'unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result


хотелось бы еще добавить дэбаги на проверку, что мне не подсовывают отрицательный размер одной из размерностей в конструкторе

А как Вам его могут "подсунуть"? Используйте беззнаковый целый тип для данного параметра.

Один из конструкторов у меня с переменным числом аргументов. Я делаю проверку на то, что тип целочисленный template <typename ...size_types, typename std::enable_if_t< std::conjunction_v<std::is_integral<size_types>...>, bool > = true>. Но потенциально может быть например char v; ...  v = -1; ... TMatrix<3, int> matrix(3, 3, v); Работать будет (и должно работать), но это же по сути UB. Хотелось бы дать возможность потенциальному пользователю произвести тестирование.

И да, конечно, для массива размерности (внутреннее поле моего TMatrix) я использую беззаковый тип и просто делаю cast при инициализации/изменении размеров.

@HalturinEvgeniy, вместо требования на интегральный тип, Вы можете требовать чтобы он был беззнаковый и умещался в std::size_t. Но весь Ваш код я не видел, поэтому немного проблематично давать точные рекомендации.

запретить int в качестве размера для своего контейнера, это как запретить int в качестве размера для vector. Будь это так в стандартной библиотеке, я бы и для своего контейнера так сделал. Но это не так.

@HalturinEvgeniy, а Вы считаете стандартную библиотеку неким эталоном? :) "Но это не так". Хорошо, я Вас понял, не настаиваю.

ну я же типа учусь. Так что пока да, стандартная библиотека для меня стандарт )))

В других ответах советуют -Wsign-conversion, однако оно ругается только на неявные преобразования и совершенно безразлично к любым переполнениям. Советуют -fsanitize=undefined, однако переполнения беззнаковых типов и изменение значения при переходе от знакового типа к беззнаковому являются определенным поведением.
Что же делать? Можно самому писать соотв. проверки и ассерты, однако все уже --украдено-- написано до нас. Например, есть бибилотека SafeInt, предоставляющая одноименный класс для проведения операций с целыми числами с контролем переполнения и прочих проблем, и набор отдельных функций для преобразований и арифметических операций:
SafeInt<unsigned int> size{-3}; // Error

Есть библиотека Boost.Safe Numerics, служащая схожим целям и предоставляющая более продвинутые опции, как то указание диапазона валидных значений для чисел вместо встроенных. Или запрет на компиляцию участков с потерями:
#include <boost/safe_numerics/safe_integer.hpp>
#include <cstdint> // uint8_t
using namespace boost::safe_numerics;

uint8_t f(uint8_t i){
    return i;
}

using safe_t = safe<long, native, loose_trap_policy>;

int main(){
    const long x = 97;
    f(x);   // OK - implicit conversion to int can never fail
    const safe_t y = 97;
    f(y);   // could overflow so trap at compile time
    return 0;
}

Даже в стандарт С++ проникают некоторые полезные новвовведения, например Saturation arithmetic, позволяющая производить приводящие к переполнению операции с отсечкой по крайнему значению вместо переполнения.
unsigned char x4{::std::add_sat<unsigned char>(253, 4)}; // получается 255

